# Specifying number of columns and rows in a raster file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2

ArcGIS 10.2

I want to produce a raster file with a specific number of rows and columns - 300x300. This needs to be reproducible on multiple data sets/locations - so fixing the extent of the file won't work.

I have tried changing the grid size which then changes the number of rows and columns but it is too awkward to make it create a 300x300 raster.

Is there a simple way of specifying these?

Answer (score 1):

If this is going to be a spatial dataset and you are posting this question on a GIS forum you need to set the extent and ideally the coordinate system. Also by definition a raster *has* to have a value for each cell. So assuming you have spatial analyst extension installed, licensed and turned on you can use the *Create Constant Raster tool*. A screen shot below shows how to create a raster with an origin at 0,0 and is 300 pixels wide and high with each pixel a 10x10m area. I did this for the British National Grid.

It's worth emphasising that there are few rasters that are useful which are anchored to 0,0 especially if you want to use it in spatial analysis with other datasets.

[image: Create constant raster tool]

Comment: Many thanks - as a newcomer to both GIS I am sorry for any simple questions! I hadn't used the create constant raster before. In my case - if i had a layer on a map which showed land use, I then converted this to a raster (1-agriculture, 2- residence (for example)), when I export this as an ASCII file I cannot get the size of the matrix to change. As in I need this matrix in a 300x300 format (300 rows and 300 columns). I am not bothered by how big or small the cells are.